# Can I set PHP's Interal Date and Time to months before?

Tags: php, time

I am wondering if I can **change PHP's overall date**, to think its really at about 2 months ago, or 2011 if I want.

If it's "*No, you must use the DateTime class and set the system up to run through there*", that would be the chosen answer.

The reason is because I have a massive project using an API thats based on many schedules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting the system date, however you *really* shouldn't.

Just use PHP's datetime and adjust accordingly. If you don't want to set the month everytime you want to use datetime functions simply create a wrapper class which does this for you and call that.

Comment: I understand. In the case Im in its my only option to save weeks of refactoring, I will try this :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP5 provides DateTime and DateInterval

2 months ago from now:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // Time now
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P2M')); // Substract a Period (P) of Two (2) Months (M)
```